# react Error: It looks like you are passing several store enhancers to createStore()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, core-ui

I am developing an application with react. I developed the application using core-ui template. But I encounter an error like the one below. Can you help with the solution?

As far as I understand, I could not create more than one  store.

Can you help with how to fix this problem

**App.js**
`

```
 import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
 import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
 import './polyfill'
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import App from './App';
 import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
 import { icons } from './assets/icons'
 import store from './store'
 import { transitions, positions, Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert'
 import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic'
 import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
 import ReactNotification from 'react-notifications-component';
 import 'react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css'

 React.icons = icons;

 const options = {
   position: positions.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
   timeout: 5000,
   offset: '1px',
   transition: transitions.SCALE,
 };

 ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>

     <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>

     <ReactNotification/>
     <App/>

   </AlertProvider>
   </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
 );
 serviceWorker.unregister();
```

`

**store.js**
`

```
 import {applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore} from 'redux'
 import customerReducer from "./components/helpers/reducers/customerReducer";
 import userReducer from "./components/helpers/reducers/userReducer";
 import appointmentsReducer from "./components/helpers/reducers/appointmenstReducer";
 import thunk from "redux-thunk";

 const initialState = {
   sidebarShow: 'responsive'
 };


 const rootReducers = combineReducers({
   customerInfo: customerReducer,
   account_profile: userReducer,
   appointmentsList: appointmentsReducer
 });
 const allEnhancers = compose(
   applyMiddleware(thunk)
 );


 const changeState = (state = initialState, { type, ...rest }) => {
   switch (type) {
     case 'set':
       return {...state, ...rest };
     default:
       return state
   }
 };

 const store = createStore(
   changeState,
   rootReducers,
   allEnhancers
 );
 export default store
```

`

[image: Changed APP.JS]
**changed App.js**
`

```
 import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11'; // For IE 11 support
 import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
 import './polyfill'
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import App from './App';
 import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
 import { icons } from './assets/icons'
 import store from './store'
 import { transitions, positions, Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert'
 import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic'
 import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
 import ReactNotification from 'react-notifications-component';
 import 'react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css'
 import {applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore} from "redux";
 import customerReducer from "./components/helpers/reducers/customerReducer";
 import userReducer from "./components/helpers/reducers/userReducer";
 import appointmentsReducer from "./components/helpers/reducers/appointmenstReducer";
 import thunk from "redux-thunk";

 React.icons = icons;

 const options = {
   position: positions.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
   timeout: 5000,
   offset: '1px',
   transition: transitions.SCALE,
 };


 const rootReducers = combineReducers({
   customerInfo: customerReducer,
   account_profile: userReducer,
   appointmentsList: appointmentsReducer
 });
 const allEnhancers = compose(
   applyMiddleware(thunk)
 );
 const store2 = createStore(
   rootReducers,
   allEnhancers,
   changeState()
 );


 const initialState = {
   sidebarShow: 'responsive'
 };
 const changeState = (state = initialState, { type, ...rest }) => {
   switch (type) {
     case 'set':
       return {...state, ...rest };
     default:
        return state
   }
 };


 ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store2}>

     <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>

     <ReactNotification/>
     <App/>

  </AlertProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
 );
 serviceWorker.unregister();
```

`

Comment: Yes, you are not able to use 2 stores. Move your changeState store to rootReducers

Comment: yes, i tried to live but this time the "changeState" function did not work.

Comment: add your `changeState` reducer to `combineReducers` and remove it from `createStore`

Comment: Can you write how to do it as I have just started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const initialState = {
   sidebarShow: 'responsive'
 };

 const changeStateReducer = (state = initialState, { type, ...rest }) => {
   switch (type) {
     case 'set':
       return {...state, ...rest };
     default:
       return state
   }
 };

 const rootReducers = combineReducers({
   customerInfo: customerReducer,
   account_profile: userReducer,
   appointmentsList: appointmentsReducer,
   changeState: changeStateReducer
 });

 const allEnhancers = compose(
   applyMiddleware(thunk)
 );

 const store = createStore(
   rootReducers,
   allEnhancers
 );

 export default store
```

Comment: yes it didn't make any mistake. But it doesn't do any of the following functions
  customerInfo: customerReducer,
   account_profile: userReducer,
   appointmentsList: appointmentsReducer,
   changeState: changeStateReducer

Comment: what do you expect to receive? It just initialise your default store

Comment: https://ibb.co/Wg8MTZN    it actually works fine. I'm not getting an error. But as in the picture, reducers information does not come.

Comment: and what's you receive on `console.log(store.getState())`?

Comment: maybe you don't understand how redux works. To change a state you need to dispatch an action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216878/discussion-between-fatih-mzm-and-demkovych).

Comment: OK reducers are working. But the drop-down menu does not work. So sidebar does not open or close

Comment: that's the other problem with implementation